# TeXStudio changed R image in pdf format

Tags: graphics, symbols

The situation is as follows: I created this chart using R Studio and then exported it in .pdf format to import it in TeXStudio:

[image]

However, after importing it into TeXStudio, all the greek letters in this chart just disappear:

[image]

Is this a known issue and if so, how could I fix this?

Here are the packages I'm using:

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. (Saudações do Brasil) Please, provide a [MWE] (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Images are not a good practice here. Tip: revise your packages. You are loading some twice. Create a new file with only the necessary files. It will help you (and us) to give better advice. Which command (or package) did you use to import the pdf?

Comment: I think FHZ means: images of code is not good practice here. Nobody want to retype your code in order to test it

Comment: Probably you saved the pdf with `ggsave`. Use `ggsave(filename,plot,device=cairo_ps,...)`. It should work if you specify the `cairo_ps` device.

Comment: @Ross Your suggestion worked. Thanks!

Comment: @FHZ sorry about not following this website's good practices. The problem was solved using Ross's advice.

Comment: I am voting to close because (a) it is an R problem, not LaTeX, and (b) the OPs question is solved in the comments.

Comment: Indeed. I failed to mention "images of codes". Ross pointed it out nicely. @Sigma, don't worry, we're here to help and provide assistance, it take a while to understand how exactly is the best way to ask for advice.

Answer (score 1):

Following Ross's suggestion, the problem was solved by saving the plot using `ggsave('trimodal1.pdf', plot=last_plot(), device=cairo_pdf, path='C:\\Users\\victor\\Desktop', dpi='retina')` instead of saving it using `R` Studio's GUI save mechanism.